# Laravel 4 pagination links empty page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I have a query returning hundreds of database records.

As I am trying to paginate it using Laravel 4.2 method. Links are showing and they direct me to `search-view?page=1` and so on, but the links open empty pages with no results. Only the first page contains results.

When I am trying to show these results without pagination the page never ends so I need to have it paginated.

Controller:

```
$results = $this->model->where($searchByColumn, '=', $searchKey)
                       ->paginate(30);

return View::make('search-view')
            ->with('results', $results);
```

View:

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
   {{$result}} <br>
@endforeach

{{$results->links()}}
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: provide the code for route `search-view` and its controller

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Route only runs the code from the first two blocks of code I provided here. There is nothing much else in there. I am getting results from database and passing them to the view, thats all.

Comment: try this `paginate($30, ['*'], 'page', $request->page);`

Comment: Have you tried `APP_DEBUG=true`? No errors in the log?

Comment: The issue is still open. Anyone :D?

Comment: @divHelper11 when you open page 2 and keep the latest laravel log file open? You can find it inside `storage/logs/` ALso empty page you meant entirely blank page or page which renders top part and stops?

Comment: i am not sure but you are paginating the **30** records in each page if the search result is **less than 30** then `pagination won't display`

Comment: $searchByColumn and $searchKey are parameters from the query string?

Comment: It finds around 1700 records collection and paginates it. The website is not entirely blank. It renders the layout and the search input like i didnt search for anything

Comment: What happens if you go directly to search-view?page=2
Do you actually land in the same controller? You could dump your collection there to see if you are getting any results. 

If that's working you can continue in the view and troubleshoot there.

Comment: Please look further at your `$this->model`   this must be the cause, the rest is fine.

Comment: Can you provide your controller's action code. i suppose that searchByColumn and searchKey are passed in query string or in your request body, if so, when you are caliing search-view?page=1, criterias are missing so the query doesn't return anything, try putting a dd($results) before the return to see if there is some data or not.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you don't see any record on the second page probably because $searchByColumn and $searchKey are not defined, that is are defined only on the first page because entered as input of a form but not on the other pages if you follow the basic paginator links.

To persist the value of $searchByColumn and $searchKey through consecutive requests you can append them to the links generated by the paginator, something like that:

```
{{ $results->appends(
    array('searchByColumn' => $searchByColumn, 
    'searchKey ' => $searchKey ))->links() }}
```

Adjust the code to follow the names of your parameters and don't forget to pass them to the view.